# Arduino communication protocol with python - beyond pyserial and Arduino example

Tags: serial, arduino-due, communication, python, robotics

TL;DR does someone know of a advance and reliable/redudent USB protocol for communicating between a raspberry pi and Arduino due (native port)

I am trying to learn how to build a little robot which I hope could be autonomous at some point. In terms of hardware I am using an Arduino Due and a raspberry pi 3. The former is connected to DC motors, servos, ultrasonic sensors, light sensors, etc... The pi is responsible for running the picam and sending controlles from an Xbox controller to the Arduino as well as running a django web interface. 
Long story short, I am trying to have python reliably communicating with the Arduino over serialusb (using the native port) but with no luck. The simple communication protocol shown in the Arduino example is too weak. I found a GitHub project named arduino-robust-serial https://github.com/araffin/arduino-robust-serial which worked at first but for reasons which are quite long to discuss here was not enough.

My question is as follows: does someone know of a reliable serial protocol around which could be used to have a raspberry pi communicating with an Arduino over usb?

I hope I'm not too vague. But looking online I'm struggling to find resources regarding Arduino which are not beginner blinking light examples.

Thx

Comment: What protocol in what "example"?

Comment: The one I was referring was the SerialEvent example in the arduino IDE

Comment: Ah that. That's really not a protocol example. Only an example of how you can do things with SerialEvent.  SerialEvent is silly, anyway. Forget it.

Comment: Good to know, so do you have a recommendation to how I could get the two to talk properly and fast, as the sensors need to transmit data to the pi in real time?

Comment: Depends very much what the data is and what quantity there is.

Comment: The pi transmits command to control the motors. Wanting to expand I the future python sends the motor's name and a value. The Arduino ois responsable from interpreting that. On the other hand the Arduino sends data from 8 ultrasonic sensors as fast as possible (ideally every 50ms) as well as a light sensor which measures the rotation of the wheels (basically within a few dozen milliseconds).  My question wasn't really a how to do it. But rather has someone proposed a serial protocol to do such thing. I would be surprised otherwise

Comment: There are many many protocols around. I myself have one called [ICSC](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/ICSC), though whether that is suitable for you or not I can't say. There's as many ways of transferring the data as there are [cats that want skinning](https://grammarist.com/phrase/more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat/). You could probably get away with a simple ASCII protocol (`M1:213\n` for example).

Comment: Why is the simple protocol from the examples too weak? Are you loosing data with it? Or what is the problem there?

Comment: indeed, I am missing data packets (e.g. the motor keep spinning even though I've sent the stop command) probably because the buffer is more than often full. and since I'm streaming data from the arduino i get to some points where everything freezes. Needless to say, that I'm not using it well, hence why i'm looking for examples of protocols such as the ICSC mentioned here or the arduino-robust-serial to see how people did it. I'm basically not very good at implementing the example shown in the aruidon IDE and am looking for what people have done so far

Comment: If your Arduino code cannot process the information fast enough, you have a general problem. At one point or another you will loose information with every communication protocol, if you cannot process the information as fast, as they are arriving. The buffers will also fill up with other interfaces. Or are your messages simply too long (more than 6 byte)? Then raise the buffer size

Comment: *more than 64 bytes - in case of Serial. Not 6 bytes, sorry, typo

Comment: Maybe if I reformulate my question: what frameworks exist for robotics applications that consider the coupling of an arduino with a raspberry pi (I'am looking into ROS.org, though it's not ideal for raspberry pi) are there modern alternatives?

Comment: why would the arduino need to transmit the signal from the wheel rotation sensor? ... that part of the system should stay in the arduino ... the arduino and the wheels should be more like a Logo turtle ... the RPi issues a command to `move ahead 10cm` and the arduino does it ... or `move ahead 10cm, but stop when bumped, and report actual distance of travel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after quite some time looking for something that would allow me to easily control an arduino with the raspberry pi, I found the [FIRMATA protocol](https://github.com/firmata/protocol) which allows one to communicate with the arduino through many languages. (a snippet from the github page for SEO purposes is shown at the end of this message).

From there I looked for through the python frameworks, and had a long chat with [MrYsLab](https://github.com/MrYsLab) who helped me integrate the arduino Due to his [pymata](https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata-aio) and [pymataExpress](https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata-express) frameworks. They work quite well and enable you to have a script that quickly and efficiently communicates with the arduino. I'm sure proper frameworks from [ros.org](http://www.ros.org) or [gobot](https://gobot.io) are better. But [pymata](https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata-aio) worked for me hence my answer to my own question.

1. processing

   - https://github.com/firmata/processing
   - http://funnel.cc
2. python

   - https://github.com/firmata/pyduino
   - https://github.com/lupeke/python-firmata
   - https://github.com/tino/pyFirmata
   - https://github.com/MrYsLab/PyMata
   - https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata-aio
3. perl

   - https://github.com/ntruchsess/perl-firmata
   - https://github.com/rcaputo/rx-firmata
4. ruby

   - https://github.com/hardbap/firmata
   - https://github.com/PlasticLizard/rufinol
   - http://funnel.cc
5. clojure

   - https://github.com/nakkaya/clodiuno
   - https://github.com/peterschwarz/clj-firmata
6. javascript

   - https://github.com/jgautier/firmata
   - http://breakoutjs.com
   - https://github.com/rwldrn/johnny-five
7. java

   - https://github.com/4ntoine/Firmata
   - https://github.com/kurbatov/firmata4j
   - https://github.com/reapzor/FiloFirmata
8. .NET

   - https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino
   - http://www.imagitronics.org/projects/firmatanet/
   - https://github.com/wbadry/FirmataCSharpClientClass
9. Flash/AS3

   - http://funnel.cc
   - http://code.google.com/p/as3glue/
10. PHP

    - https://bitbucket.org/ThomasWeinert/carica-firmata
    - https://github.com/oasynnoum/phpmake_firmata
11. Haskell

    - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hArduino
12. iOS

    - https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/iosfirmata
13. Dart

    - https://github.com/nfrancois/firmata
14. Max/MSP

    - http://www.maxuino.org/
15. Elixir

    - https://github.com/kfatehi/firmata
16. Modelica

    - https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/model-plug/
17. golang

    - https://github.com/kraman/go-firmata
18. Qt/QML

    - https://github.com/callaa/qfirmata
19. Android/Kotlin

    - https://github.com/xujiaao/android-firmata
20. Smalltalk

    - https://github.com/pharo-iot/Firmata